# Why is the d subshell only stable when all of its orbitals are filled?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, electrons, electronic-configuration

I was learning about the Aufbau principle and quantum electronic configuration. Here are some of the yet-unanswered queries that I wish to know the answers to.

1. I discovered that the d subshell is only stable when each of its orbitals is either filled with a single electron or a pair of electrons. Why is it so?
2. What causes electrons to first fill up each orbital rather than to exist in the same orbital with opposite spins (in subshells other than s, obviously)?
3. Thirdly, if the 3d subshell has more energy than the 4s subshell, isn't it plausible that electrons are shared/transferred from the 3d subshell first, and then from the 4s subshell? Why doesn't it happen?

Comment: Mathjax is discouraged in titles, also subshell notations need to be upright. Andselisk was just correcting that.

Comment: Ad 3: Order of electrons energies in particular orbitals is not fixed, but depends on electron configuration, which affects electron mutual shielding and repulsion. The typical case are early actinoids, behaving rather like d elements, instead of f element behaviour in the prior period.

Comment: What do you mean by "stable" in your first question? What behaviour distinguishes "unstable" d shell fillings from stable ones?

Comment: Doesn't your first question apply to s and p orbitals too? Aren't p orvitals also unstable if they ate not completely or half filled?

Answer (score 2):

I'll try #2

> What causes electrons to first fill up each orbital rather than to exist in the same orbital with opposite spins (in subshell other than s, obviously)?

This is known as Hund's rule of maximum multiplicity: For a given electron configuration, the lowest energy is the one with the greatest value of spin multiplicity.

According to Ira Levine's *Quantum Chemistry*, the explanation is conceptually related to the Pauli exclusion principle. Pauli's exclusion principle forbids identical quantum numbers for two electrons around an atom. Applied to this situation, the principle is that electrons with the same spin in the same shell and subshell must be in orbitals with different magnetic quantum numbers m. The related concept is that when every quantum number is the same except m, a kind of spatial Pauli repulsion exists between such similar electrons.

The traditional explanation was that electrons with the same spin avoid each other, and that leads to a lower energy due to less electron-electron repulsion. Calculations in the 1970s showed that this was wrong. In some simple cases, the average distance between the two electrons was actually a little less (with more repulsion) for same-spin electrons than opposite-spin electrons.

The actual reason isn't distance between the electrons but a similar spatial concept. If you create an angle with the nucleus at the vertex and two electrons determining the rays, electrons with same spins create a greater angle on average than electrons with different spins. This reduces the chance that one electron will screen the other and allows the electrons to get closer to the nucleus on average (with more attraction) for same-spin electrons than opposite-spin electrons.

Answer (score 1):

I can tackle #3, which is a bit of a subtle question.

In the transition elements of the fourth period, the $3d$ subshell lies at higher energy than the $4s$ subshell -- **when the atoms are neutral.** But the electronic energy levels change when you remove typically two or three electrons to form an ion of any of these elements in their most common salts.

Think of an ion with some number of protons in the nucleus and just one electron. The energy levels of the electron (though *not* the electron as such) follow the model constructed by Bohr, whereby the single $1s$ orbital is at one energy level; the $2s$ and $2p$ orbitals, which Bohr's model just called the second shell, are at another higher, single energy level; the third shell is at one still higher level, and so on. Thus the electron in what we now call a $3d$ orbital, part of the third shell, would be at lower energy than it would be in the $4s$ orbital in the fourth shell.

Real atoms and ions in ordinary chemistry, apart from hydrogen, are more complicated. They have multiple electrons which repel one another even as they are all attracted to the nucleus, and the quantum mechanical theories that succeeded the Bohr model show that the shells are no longer all at one energy level. What Bohr rendered as "the" energy level for the second shell ends up becoming a lower level for the $2s$ orbital plus a higher level for the $2p$ orbital; the interactions of the electrons with each other as well as the nucleus cause the higher angular momentum states (one unit for $p$, zero for $s$) states to have higher energy. Higher angular momentum states basically get higher in energy by avoiding the regions closest to the nucleus and intermingling more with other electrons.

When we get to the fourth period transition elements, the neutral atoms generally have just enough electrons for the higher angular momentum ($l=2$) $3d$ subshell to sneak above the higher-shell but lower angular momentum ($l=0$) $4s$ subshell. But taking (generally) two or three of those outer electrons away to form the commonly encountered ions means the interelectronic repulsions are reduced, and with that there is less separation of subshell energy levels within a single shell. The $3d$ subshell drops towards its lower angular momentum shell-mates and below the $4s$ orbital, so that the most stable form of the ion now has its outer electrons all in $3d$.

Comment: But I believe a part of that question has still not been answered - why are $4s$ electrons lost first if $3d$ electrons have more energy, albeit they owe it to $l$ (before losing electrons, the atom is neutral)?

Comment: The $3d$ electrons might be lost, but them when the $3d$ level drops it can swipe a $4s$ electron into a more stable state. We would not becable to tell this experimentally because according to quantum mechanics, electrons do not carry little tags saying which subshell of an atom they came from.